# eCommerce with Hybris: Email Template Generation

Tags: email, sap-commerce-cloud

Hello Experts,
                 I am newbie to Hybris Ecommerce and currently i am working on generating hybris email template for B2C.I am following the below link :

```
http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/index.php/ecommerce-with-hybris-sending-emails/
```

Email Context Object :

```
public class OneMillionPurchaseEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext
{
    // ...

    @Override
    public void init(final BusinessProcessModel businessProcessModel, final EmailPageModel emailPageModel)
    {
        // ...
        put(FROM_EMAIL, emailPageModel.getFromEmail());
        put(FROM_DISPLAY_NAME, emailPageModel.getFromName());
        put(DISPLAY_NAME, "BDI Customer Service");
        put(EMAIL, getCustomerEmailResolutionService().getEmailForCustomer(getCustomer()));
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected BaseSiteModel getSite(final BusinessProcessModel businessProcessModel)
    {
        return ((StoreFrontProcessModel) businessProcessModel).getSite();
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomerModel getCustomer(final BusinessProcessModel businessProcessModel)
    {
        return ((StoreFrontCustomerProcessModel) businessProcessModel).getCustomer();
    }
}
```

In the above code,Can anyone guide me from where we have to call this email context Object class?It would be appreciated if anyone can guide or provide any links or docs for email template generation configuration process.

Comment: Try this : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/sending-emails-in-hybris/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called from `platform/acceleratorservices/process/email/context/impl/DefaultEmailContextFactory.java`
Then this is used in `platform/acceleratorservices/email/impl/DefaultEmailGenerationService.java`
which is in a standard hybris extension. In order for the Factory to resolve your context, you must have a bean in your -spring.xml configuration for `OneMillionPurchaseEmailContext` .

For more information, i would recommend the [hybris wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/Email+WCMS+and+Process+Engine+Integration+in+the+hybris+Multichannel+Accelerator)

Comment: Hi Hristo.. I am also using the above mentioned link by @User2413 but in the mail-process.xml file, my code is unable to execute the very first node which is: generateOneMillionPurchaseEmail . When I go the HMC in business process, it says Something Went Wrong. I have double checked my smtp settings and everything is fine. Can you please suggest something ?

Comment: Do you see any errors or exceptions on your backend console log ?

Comment: Yes. I found this error : de.hybris.platform.media.exceptions.MediaNotFoundException: Media not found (requested media location: h8a/h70/8806300811294.bin) at de.hybris.platform.media.storage.impl.LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.getAsStream(LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy )   but I am not getting what is it looking for. I ran all the impexes for email templates as well.

Comment: Well apparently it is looking for some location "h8a/h70/8806300811294.bin" and can't find it. So here the problem is not exactly in the email process, but somewhere in the file system. :) I would search a path like and see what is in there and why it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not call this Context. It is used as part of the generation of your email. That page doesn't seem to mention the RendererTemplate. Have a look at the lines at the end of one of the sample "email-content.impex".